# Adding Map templates to Layout View in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, layers, layouts, template

I have installed ArcGIS 10.3 (on Windows 7 Pro) for desktop and it works very well. There is only e little problems: when I go to "layout view" and open "select template", the windows that appears don't contains only "My Templates" and not the the templates like ISO A Page Size, or Architectural Page Size, and so on. How can I take the Map Templates folders and bring them into the Select templates (or into Getting Started)?

My Select template:

[image: my Select template]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCzBo.png)

Select Template how it must be:
[image: Select Template how it must be![2]];